# How to load Mbox content based on dropdown selection and not on Page load?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, mbox

I have several MBoxes on the asp.net page, all other Mboxes are supposed to work on page load as it is, however I want to add one new MBox to page. I want to pass custom parameters to the new Mbox based on the dropdown selected value. Hence I do not want to load the MBox on page load because that time dropdown does not have any value selected. Once user selects value in the dropdown, I want to create new Mbox and fire call to T&T to show content specific to selected Dropdown value. When user selects new dropdown value, new dropdown value should be passed to T&T and content should load accordingly. Please guide me to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I added a javascript code to call `mboxDefine` on the dropdown selection event, followed by `mboxUpdate`. Something like this

```
mboxDefine('someId','mboxName','param1=value1','param2=value2');
 mboxUpdate('mboxName','param3=value3','param4=value4');
```